# Trouble with changing the placeholder color of md-select

Tags: css, html, angular-material

I've tried to change the placeholder color of md-select, but it's not working:

**CSS**

```
md-select::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;}
```

**HTML**

```
<md-select ng-model="weapon" placeholder="Navaneethan@gmail.com" class="md-no-underline" style="margin-top:5px">
  <md-option value="axe">option1</md-option>
  <md-option value="axe">option2</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Help me to change the color of the placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify your **CSS** as:

```
.md-no-underline span  {
  color: teal;  // custom color here
}
```

Check out [this](http://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/YpLBEv) pen.

Comment: This ruins the red color when input is invalid. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Not sure. This answer is pretty old, most probably the library has undergone a lot of changes by now.